# Having trouble in selecting ToolStrip button in Windows Form C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms-designer

I have this toolstrip on my windows form. When double clicking on ToolStrip button it gives me

my designer view:

[image]

my code view:

[image]

I'm wanting to have a button click event on every button and have a click event like on the image below.

their designer view:

[image]

their code view:

[image]

it seems like I can't click on the button directly, rather it selected the whole toolstrip instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the icon in the top left, this is netcore, or net5. Some things in winforms designer on these platforms are still very wonky and toolstrip related things seem to be one of them..

Change to winforms on .net framework if you can, or add your click event handlers in code if you can't:

1. write the name of your button in code, followed by `.Click +=`
2. Accept the suggestion to insert a method for you by pressing tab

Comment: thanks for your answer but I did it by using the small arrow in the upper right corner of the toolStrip(seen on the first image) then edit items, there I added the buttons and icons. I didn't seem to find any ⚡events there.

Comment: And when you click on the button (once) in the form designer main view, you do not see the properties grid on the right show it's properties? How about right clicking the button and choosing Properties?

Comment: when i'm clicking on the buttons in the designer, it seems that I can't click on them one by one. when I do click(left or right) it highlights the whole ToolStrip and show its name(ToolStrip1) in the properties.

Comment: Thanks for this! Answered. turns out I'm not using .net framework and using .net core all along. done my research and found out they are not the same. Though they have similarities but they're not the same.

Comment: .NET framework is "going away", though not any time soon. Microsoft has said v4.8 will be the last version, and all efforts switch to focusing on .NET 5 which is essentially the next version of .net core. I recall reading that a large amount of work was done to make winforms work with .net core/5 but I think it should be regarded as a work in progress - microsoft advocate setting up two projects, one .net framework and one .net core, do your design work in .net FW one but then "add existing item" to get the form into the netcore app, but always edit in .net framework version

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/blob/main/docs/winforms-designer.md

Comment: Yes .NET FW is quite old. I remembered using it in my high school days. and because of these I tried to use the latest .NET for my winforms project. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Probably everything in computing is quite old.. the underpinnings of Windows 10 are from around 25 years ago. Newer isn't always better, especially for winforms :) but the net framework of today will be a fair bit different to what you used back then, 4.8 having not long been released

Answer (score 0):

It's because you doubled click the **whole ToolStrip** not the **buttons on the ToolStrip**